# gnuplot set key at position and later move

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot I'm trying to set the key at a specific position for a few plots, and then later I just want it in the bottom right corner of the screen. I tried:

```
set key at -5, 5
plot x
set key bottom right
replot
```

but the key doesn't move to the bottom right. How do I make gnuplot forget that I previously set a specific key location?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It only seems to be a problem if you use `set key at`

I got round it be adding `set key default` before the `set key bottom right`

```
set key at -5, 5
plot x
set key default
set key bottom right
replot
```